# Error: Invalid argument prepareInjection.js:640:17 JQuery/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to build a simple app that should be fetching a curl API using PHP and JQuery, and even though the API seems to be working, whenever I try to fetch the data using JQuery to display it in my frontend (HTML) it doesn't return anything.

Whenever I try and open my PHP app that's the error that gets returned:

Error: Invalid argument                                     prepareInjection.js:640:17

See my script.js below:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    if ($('#preloader').length) { $('#preloader').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); }); }
});

$('#coordinates').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/api.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            north: $('#North').val(),
            south: $('#South').val(),
            east: $('#East').val(),
            west: $('#West').val(),
        },
        success: function (result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result) {
                $('#clouds').html(result['data'][0]['clouds']);
                $('#temperature').html(result['data'][0]['temperature']);
                $('#station').html(result['data'][0]['stationname']);


            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        }
    });

});
```

Below my PHP code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url =
    'http://api.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=kyleghilotti';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($data, true);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your error is anywhere in this code. Where is line 640 of `prepareInjection.js`?

Comment: I believe the prepareinjection.js is the file from some browser extension. I have the same problem now - it is in Firefox, but I have no idea, which extension it is.

Comment: So in my case helped to disable this extension: https://github.com/dpacassi/disable-javascript - I have no idea way. Firefox worked 15 mins ago and suddenly stopped (there was no update meantime). Disabling this extension helped.